# Magento 2. How to fetch available shipping methods for current customer

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, customer-address, magento-2.1.9

I'd like to know how can I fetch all shipping careers available for the current customer (quote wasn't created yet).

Answer (score 1):

i don't know do you find any way but i am work around this now .
i get all shipping method and pass the param that each shipping method needed for example :

```
  /**
     * @var $free \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping
     * @var $req \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest
     */
    $free=$this->_objectManager->create("Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping");
    $req=$this->_objectManager->create("Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest");
    $req->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(10);
    $res= $free->collectRates($req);
  //  var_dump($res->getRatesByCarrier("freeshipping")->asArray());

    $rates = [];
    foreach ($res->getAllRates() as $rate) {
        $rates[$rate->getCarrier()]['title'] = $rate->getCarrierTitle();
        $rates[$rate->getCarrier()]['methods'][$rate->getMethod()] = [
            'title' => $rate->getMethodTitle(),
            'price' => $rate->getPrice(),
            'price_formatted' => 111,
        ];
    }
    var_dump($rates);
```

and now i can find this shipping method can be available or not.
if you have a better way or find any thing please share it